# Using Redis cache with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redis, entity-framework-6

I'm using [EFCache.Redis](https://github.com/silentbobbert/EFCache.Redis) library in an ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6 project for caching query results. There are some good examples in the [test project](https://github.com/silentbobbert/EFCache.Redis/tree/master/EFCache.Redis.Tests) of this package:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Item_cached()
    {
        var cache = new RedisCache("localhost:6379");
        var item = new TestObject { Message = "OK" };

        cache.PutItem("key", item, new string[0], TimeSpan.MaxValue, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);

        object fromCache;

        Assert.IsTrue(cache.GetItem("key", out fromCache));
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Message, ((TestObject)fromCache).Message);

        Assert.IsTrue(cache.GetItem("key", out fromCache));
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Message, ((TestObject)fromCache).Message);
    }
```

But what I need is something like a helper class to avoid repeating the code. So I write this code:

```
public class CacheManager : ICacheManager
{

    private RedisCache _cache;
    public CacheManager()
    {
        _cache = new RedisCache("localhost:6379");
    }

    public object GetCache(string key, Func<object> factory, string[] relatedEntitties = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            throw new Exception("Cache key cannot be null");

        if (relatedEntitties == null)
            relatedEntitties = new string[0];

        object fromCache;
        _cache.GetItem(key, out fromCache);

        if (fromCache == null)
        {
            fromCache = factory();
            _cache.PutItem(key, fromCache, relatedEntitties, TimeSpan.MaxValue, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
        }

        return fromCache;
    }

    public void InvalidateCache(string key)
    {
        _cache.InvalidateItem(key);
    }

    public void InvalidateSets(string[] sets)
    {
        _cache.InvalidateSets(sets);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
var artists = cacheManager.GetCache("artists", () => getArtists(), new string[] { "Artist" });
```

"getArtists" method:

```
    private List<Artist> getArtists()
    {
        var artists = new List<Artist>();

        using (var ctx = new MusicStoreContext())
        {
            artists = ctx.Artists.ToList();
        }

        return artists;
    }
```

In "GetCache" method, I check if entity exists in the cache, I use it, otherwise query from database. There is no problem with this part, but something I'm not sure about is connecting to the redis server that I implemented in the class constructor. With this way everywhere I create a CacheManager instance, it tries to connect to the server. I don't know is it true? Or it should connect once? Can I set this class static? Generally I want to know the best implementation for a helper class for this if anyone knows a better way.

Comment: Try posting this in code review instead. In general I think you should abstract the cache behind something like IDistributedCache or your own singleton provider so you don't have to interact directly with Redis from your services or even your cache manager.